# Is there a way to report off Outlook for response time, total emails, and more?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, report

I'm looking for a way to report out daily how many emails came in, the time they came in, response time, subject and then a field for the body of the email. Is this possible?

Comment: Outlook doesn't give this information out of the box. You need a 3rd party plugin or use a helpdesk type system.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no a build-in way for this. But you can create a Search Folder as a workaround. Click Folder > New Search Folder > Custom > Create a custom Search Folder > Choose  > Criteria.. > Advanced > Field > Data/Time fields > Received > Condition: Today > Add to list > Ok.

Answer (score 0):

No way out of the box. I can recommend the free [Outlook Message Response Time Statistics](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookReportMessagesResponse) reporting tool. There are also reports for message stats by date, etc. Please note that I'm one of the developers of the mentioned tool.